# I want to create this type of xml file using jaxb in eclipse

Tags: xml, jaxb

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
      <action-root>
       <action name="EMPLOYERS">
    <name>EMPLOYERS</name>
    <version>12</version>
    <param>5</param>
      </action>
     </action-root>
```

heey i want to print below xml file data in unmarshalling so what changes should i make changes

Comment: you should use like this @XmlRootElement(name = "action-root") before public class ActionRoot

Comment: okk but can i have to create 2 classes ,one for action and other for rep-params because i have created an xml file that display only one <action name="EMPLOYERS"> not other one i.e. <rep-params id="0" name="P_LOCATION_ID">oadd_location_id</rep-params>

Comment: Do you want to ignore total rep-params tags in the output ??

Comment: no i dont want to ignore that one also .. i want to display both one

Comment: I am not getting the point update the  question with Excepted output xml file

Comment: i have created xml file as <action-root>
   <action name="EMPLOYERS"> 
     <report-name>EMPLOYERS</report-name>
  <report-version>12</report-version>
  <rep-no-of-param>5</rep-no-of-param></action></action- root> but dont know how to display                                                <rep-params id="0" name="P_LOCATION_ID">oadd_location_id</rep-params>
      <rep-params id="1" name="P_FINYEAR_ID">oadd_fin_year_id</rep-params>

Comment: @Naren: i want to print the data from xml file as mentiond above so what changes should i do in unmarshalling file becoz when i m going to print data n it will generate an errot that report version not found

Comment: First check ur input xml file contains report-version tag or not and use TestUnMarshalXML.java to unmarshall and add action.getReportVersion() in Syso

Comment: i have add sys out but five nullpointer exception so i dont understand how to do that can u justify in detail...

Comment: I have edited TestUnMarshalXML.java just copy paste and run..Even if you get the NullPointerException Update your Question with That Exception Stacktrace.. I will find the exact cause... Note:- UnMarshalling Means XML--> Java Objects

Comment: @Naren it just showing the first action data not 2nd action .for 2nd it is raise an nullpointer exception bcoz in 2nd action there is no <report-varsion> so is there any jaxb method to check xml tag present or not xml file in unmarshalling file

Comment: Ok Can u send XSD of that XML file

Comment: sorry to say that i dont create xsd file and dont know how to create xsd from xml file

Comment: Ok then tell me what are all the possible combinations of the XMl files then we can build the XSD, Then we can Regenerate classes which can support ur Solution..Means How many action tags will be there  in action-root tag,which elements are optional,which are Mandatory if mandatory how many times they can occur in the xml file

Comment: bro finally i done it......

Comment: Good @Shamkant Jogi ..But keep it in mind first u need build XSD then according to XML..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you can do this way ..it is simple compared to above

ActionRoot.java

```
package com.naren;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "action"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "action-root")
public class ActionRoot {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Action action;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the action property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ActionRoot.Action }
     *     
     */
    public Action getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the action property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ActionRoot.Action }
     *     
     */
    public void setAction(Action value) {
        this.action = value;
    }

}
```

Action.java

```
package com.naren;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "reportName", "reportVersion",
        "repNoOfParam", "repParams" })
public class Action {

    @XmlElement(name = "report-name", required = true)
    private String reportName;
    @XmlElement(name = "report-version")
    private int reportVersion;
    @XmlElement(name = "rep-no-of-param")
    private int repNoOfParam;
    @XmlElement(name = "rep-params")
    private List<RepParams> repParams;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    public int getReportVersion() {
        return reportVersion;
    }

    public void setReportVersion(int reportVersion) {
        this.reportVersion = reportVersion;
    }

    public int getRepNoOfParam() {
        return repNoOfParam;
    }

    public void setRepNoOfParam(int repNoOfParam) {
        this.repNoOfParam = repNoOfParam;
    }

    public List<RepParams> getRepParams() {
        return repParams;
    }

    public void setRepParams(List<RepParams> repParams) {
        this.repParams = repParams;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

RepParams.java

```
package com.naren;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
public class RepParams {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;
    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

FOR marshaling TESTXMLGEN.java

```
package com.naren;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class TestXMLGen {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ActionRoot actionRoot = new ActionRoot();
        Action action = new Action();
        action.setName("EMPLOYERS");
        action.setRepNoOfParam((byte) 5);
        action.setReportVersion((byte) 12);
        action.setReportName("EMPLOYERS");
        List<RepParams> list = new ArrayList<RepParams>();

        RepParams repParams = new RepParams();
        repParams.setId((byte) 0);
        repParams.setName("P_LOCATION_ID");
        repParams.setValue("oadd_location_id");

        RepParams repParams2 = new RepParams();
        repParams2.setId((byte) 1);
        repParams2.setName("P_FINYEAR_ID");
        repParams2.setValue("oadd_fin_year_id");
        list.add(repParams);
        list.add(repParams2);
        action.setRepParams(list);
        actionRoot.setAction(action);
        try {

            File file = new File("file.xml");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext1 = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(ActionRoot.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext1.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(actionRoot, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(actionRoot, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

For UnMArshalling TestUnMarshalXML.java

```
 package com.naren;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class TestUnMarshalXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {

            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ActionRoot.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            ActionRoot aroot = (ActionRoot) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            Action action = aroot.getAction();
            List<RepParams> repParams=action.getRepParams();
            System.out.println(action.getName()+"\t"+action.getReportName()+"\t"+action.getReportVersion());
            for(RepParams rp:repParams)
                System.out.println(rp.getId()+"\t"+rp.getName()+"\t"+rp.getValue());

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
}
```